# How can I send google sheets with the script

Tags: google-sheets

I have google sheets with a script included (the script is a simple function that I made to calculate something in the sheet). I want to send it to my colleague.

When I try to download it and send it or open it locally I get error msg "Unknow function".

How can I download it and send it to my colleague with the script included?

Comment: you cant download google sheets. send him/her a link and tell him/her to authorize the script for him/herself

Comment: You can share the script through a shareable link or add their email and set the permissions. However, you cannot download the script itself

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of alternatives.

#### Solution 1

Create a new "demo" sheet, include the script, change permissions to `Anyone with the link can edit` (or view), send them the link and ask them to make a copy of it.
*You could also send them just the link to it with `copy` instead of `edit` in the end of it* *(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxx/copy`)*

#### Solution 2

Copy the script to a simple text file (`.txt`) and send them the file. They can then copy/paste it using the `Script editor` on their sheet.
*NOTE: Do not use any Word processor (like Office Word, Google Docs, etc) because they leave residue of entities that could render the code unusable.*